# MK V (06) Jetta passenger window motor

Tags: vw, jetta, power-windows

I have a 2006 Jetta. The passenger window is moving slowly. I went to Autozone to see if I could order just the window motor and replace it, but they said I had to buy the whole regulator setup. I sort-of thought that was unnecessary (and more expensive). The window is not moving out of line, it's just slow.

So my question is: Do I need to replace the regulator or is there a way to just swap out the motor?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to swap out the regulator. On "regular" parts sites, you can find the regulator separate from the motor. In fact, my goto site doesn't even show them as a single unit. For your reference, if you do a Google search for the following parts, you should be able to find what you need:

- Front Left - **A-1 CARDONE 472087**
- Front Right - **A-1 CARDONE 472086**
- Rear Left - **A-1 CARDONE 472091**
- Rear Right - **A-1 CARDONE 472092**

You can also get the fronts only, without the control module with: **A-1 CARDONE 4721**

**ACI** can provide the **rear** ones (with modules) using the part numbers: **389517** (L) & **389518** (R).

For your edification, to figure out if you're looking at the right or left side of the car, think of it sitting in the driver's seat, not standing in front of your vehicle.

Comment: @Nicholas Vivo, how how do you know the fault is in the motor? The reason for slowdown might be in the other machinery (cables, pivots, rollers, sliding bearings) which facilitate window movement.